# Template Menu Assignment Is Grayed Out

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am having an issue where I cannot unassign the index.php's theme (along with two other pages) from one theme/style and onto another. :( I've tried to change themes and then change it back to this one, I've also tried to delete the template (which does not work because "cannot delete root folder"). I've done nothing aside from selecting another theme which I am trying to change from to another theme

Please help

[image]

Comment: Sorry about that. New to this forum, though I should know better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to apply a different template for the frontend? If that's the case - go back to previous menu and set as default other template - for example `protostar` or what you have installed last.

Menu assignment checkboxes grayed out:

> Note: If a checkbox is grayed out and cannot be checked then it could be because the menu item is in use by another user. You can see if this is the case by going to the menu manager screen for the menu concerned. If there is a padlock symbol next to the menu item then it is currently in use by another user.
>   Source: 
>   [Joomla! Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Extensions_Template_Manager_Styles_Edit)

Check your Menu Manager for padlocks like that in the picture below and unlock them. [image]

Comment: Yes I do. However, the selection menu is grayed out there as well

Comment: So this is grayed? [Template Manager: Styles](http://postimg.org/image/6mco9xpfz/)

Comment: No, I have the template already selected as default and the home page has not changed.

Comment: If you change default template for the frontend (site) you should clean the cache in Joomla too. `System`->`Clear cache`, select all, `Delete`. Refresh browser. (better with Ctrl-F5).

Comment: Clearing cache didn't do anything. My site looks the same: hccts.org . Yet http://hccts.org/index.php/about-us shows the theme I want

Comment: Pls check my edit up. Do you have locked menu items (with padllock icon) like [this](http://s1.postimg.org/5ngkssopb/Capture2.png)? It is possible to happen if more than one administrator is logged and working in the backend.

Comment: Huh! There are padlocked items and they are the ones that will not assign! Very strange (as I'm checking at ~3AM at the moment)!!! Thanks a million!

Comment: This worked, you are the BEST! Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to help you.